# AngularJS - Binding when initial value is null doesn't update after it's updated

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an case where my binding does not update, and I think I understand why it might be happening, but am unsure of how to resolve it.

In my controller, I have a `company` object that has a property `user`, which may or may not contain the user. That user is another object.

This only happens when I don't have a user for the company. When I go to display the user's name on my template, I'll do the `{{ companyCtrl.company.user.name || 'N/A' }}`. So it will display `N/A` since there's no user. I would then assign a user and in the response, update `company.user` so that it's not null anymore.

However, in my template, it still shows `N/A`. I'm assuming it's because since there was no user initially, there was no binding?

But I'm not positive. In the event I did already have a user when the page loaded, and simply changed the user, the name would update in the template.

Comment: Could you create [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so that we can replicate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm finding this tricky to explain, but - when you assign companyCtrl.company.user to a new object, the reference to companyCtrl.company.user.name in the template still points to the original object, which is still null. If you want this to work, you would assign the properties of companyCtrl.company.user to the values found in the user you wish to assign to, rather than the whole object.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, and that's a good point. I actually have a service that handles the updates. If the property exists, I do an `angular.copy()` to solve that issue of the update. But I may have to take a look at my code for properties that are null, because that's probably not being accounted for.

Comment: Now that I think about it, you should be able to solve this most easily by declaring companyCtrl.company.user = {}; in the beginning of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you update scope value outside of angular (for example on jQuery callback) you should call `$scope.$apply()` or `$scope.$digest()` or `$scope.$evalAsync()` to let angular digest your data.

Answer (score 0):

It's because digest runs before the model gets updated. To force a digest, you can put your code inside a $timeout.